# Unwanted whitespace on the right of all the content

Tags: html, css

I have a website that I'm working on with css and html, somehow I have a large amount of white space next to my content which appears only when you scroll to the right. Is there some way to reduce the viewing area or the view width of the website?

I've tried decreasing the `view-width` in the `width` command in css but that removes the white space, I've tried using `width: 20%` and adjusting it but that didn't work either.

here is the code for my body element

```
* {
   margin: 0%;
   padding: 0%;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
   font-family: Poppins, sans-serif;
   color: black;


}
```

here is the link to the website
https://mentalwelfare.000webhostapp.com/
I think the problem occurs in smaller screen, im on a MacBook pro with 13.3-inch (2560 x 1600) screen so maybe bigger screens wouldn't have the problem.

I hope to be able to remove the unwanted whitespace on the right of the content.

Comment: This is due to your `<div class="cover-image">` and `<p id="q">` stretching out longer than your screen width. You could add  `overflow-x: hidden` to `<main class="main-section">` or `<body>` to truncate the overflow, but that may not be your best option as that only treats the symptom but not the underlying problem. A better option might be to make your website responsive, such as by hiding the image or wrapping it in a separate line when the window width is too narrow. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design

Comment: Please don't use 000webhost - they store your pasword in plaintext and have been breached multiple times (exposing 13 million of their customers' passwords). See the [**TroyHunt**](https://www.troyhunt.com/breaches-traders-plain-text-passwords/) and [**Sophos**](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2015/10/30/webhosting-company-loses-13m-plaintext-passwords/) reports on the issue.

Comment: @ObsidianAge thank you for telling me this, I will switch to a different Webhost soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was due to css property `right: -670px;`.

```
#q {
    ............
    right: -670px;
    top: -299px;
}
```

If you are trying to use `<p> I'm bipolar, but I'm not crazy and I never was. I'm stark raving sane.” </p>` as the image caption then just place it within the `div` of `img`.

```
<div class="cover-image">
    <img src="/img/cover-page.jpg" alt="cover-page">
    <p id="q">“I'm bipolar, but I'm not crazy and I never was. I'm stark raving sane.”</p>
</div>
```

And then you can just avoid using this CSS property

```
#q {
    position: relative;
    right: -670px;
    top: -299px;
}
```